# Calling a function with an integral type as a template parameter results in compiler error

Tags: c++, c++-templates

I have the following class

```
template <typename ScalarT, std::size_t Dims = 3, std::size_t LeafMaxSize = 15>
class KDTreeFlann {
  template <size_t CNT>
  void SearchHybridParallel(...);
}
```

The I instantiate it and want to call it like this:

```
KDTreeFlann<TypeParam, 3> kdtree(points);
kdtree.SearchHybridParallel<2>(...);
```

However, I get a compiler error:

```
error: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator<’
   kdtree.SearchHybridParallel<2>(...);
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
```

It parses the expression as kdtree.SearchHybridParallel < 2 and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `kdtree.template SeachHybridParallel<2>(...)`

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/W1o6WY5G4). Show a [mcve]. To the extent there is a problem, it lies in the code not shown. The error suggests that the call to `SearchHybridParallel` appears before the definition of `SearchHybridParallel` template, so the compiler doesn't know it's a template and thinks `<` might be a less-than operator.